# Install private azure repository by dependencies in package.jso n

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, package.json

I have created a repository with UI components which I want to reuse in separate apps. Does anybody knows how I can install private Azure repo by adding it in dependencies of package.json?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to reuse a package in separate apps, then you can package the components and publish to the Azure DevOps feed. Then configure your project and reference the published packages by adding them in dependencies of package.json.

See [Azure Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/feeds?view=azure-devops) for details. NuGet Package for your reference in this blog : [Publish to an Internal NuGet Feed in Azure DevOps](https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/publish-internal-nuget-feed/) and [Get started with NuGet packages in Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can I use it like as in git repos: "dependencies": {
    "repository1name": "git+https://github.com/myusername/repository1.git",
    "repository2name": "git+https://github.com/myusername/repository2.git"
} but with azure

Comment: @Nameless @Nameless In theory it is possible. `"dependencies": {
"GitRepo": "git+https://user:token@dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/<GitRepo>.git"
}`. However, Azure DevOps provides [Artifacts feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/feeds?view=azure-devops), basically we can use feeds to manage the packages.

Comment: @Nameless May I know any updates? Is the answer helpful?